# Android ContentProvider to access a list of exercises?

Tags: android, web-scraping, android-contentprovider

I am working on an android fitness app and I want to get the hang of using ContentProviders. I was thinking about using the myfitnesspal api to get a list of exercises, but the api is private and my request has not been addressed yet. Then I considered scraping exercises from a website--but I am a little concerned about the reliability of this approach (if the site goes down, app won't keep working).

What is the best way to go about this? Is it "safe" to get information from a website (rather than an api) with a ContentProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me If I am wrong. You want user to acces your data even if there is not web API active. So my thought for it would be

1. Download all the data from web API and store it in database
2. create an node to check if data has been updated in the API if updated download new data in background and update the database else show same data from database

Benefits

1. User don't need to download data all the time they use app and their volume of internet would be saved
2. User don't need to see blank page if there's not any data

Answer (score 0):

If im wrong, i would really like to know.. but the answer is simple: a `ContentProvider` allows only the connection to a database in your cellphone. You can't use a `ContentProvider` to get data from the internet. What you're trying to do is achievable with a `WebService`, which is an application running on a determined domain on the Internet and allows you to call some pre-defined methods linked to URLs of this same domain (but i imagine you know about that, right?).